# Selecting graphs in GraphDB using filter exists does not seem to work

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am running a query to select all graphs using filter exists, like this

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  graph ?g { filter exists { ?s ?p ?o  } }
}
```

but its response is

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [
      "g"
    ]
  },
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

and I am pretty sure that the triplestore store has graphs.

Note: the more classic query works but takes a while, so I was hoping this would improve performance.

```
select distinct ?g where { 
    graph ?g {
         ?s ?p ?o 
    }
}
```

I double-checked on Jena Fuseki and there the `filter exists` works.

Comment: the classic query would be `select distinct ?g where { 
    graph ?g { }
}` - this query is also highly optimized on Jena do do just what it has to do as efficiently as possible

Comment: also what means *"I am pretty sure that the triplestore store has graphs"* - did you load data into named graphs or not? Or are you taking about vendor specific named graphs to store e.g. triple store specific internal stuff?

Comment: To answer both of your questions: I am aware of `select distinct ?g where { graph ?g { } }` but that never worked on Virtuoso nor on GraphDB. I was trying to find another way. The "pretty sure" means that there are graphs as I mentioned that the `?g { ?s ?p ?o }` query works.